# PHP - Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_IF

Tags: php

Im getting Parse error from:

```
$uphalfh = if(isset($price30in)) { echo $price30in->textContent;}
if(isset($price30out)) { echo ", " . $price30out->textContent; }
```

How can I improve this code to avoid Parse error? **I understand that I can't use IF statement in $var**

When I **Echo Variable's** its works like a charm and I get the results that I want. But how can I assign the result of **Echo Variable's** (on Line:10) to $uphalfh

```
include_once './wp-config.php';
include_once './wp-load.php';
include_once './wp-includes/wp-db.php';

// A name attribute on a <td>
$price30in = $xpath->query('//td[@class=""]')->item( 1);
$price30out = $xpath->query('//td[@class=""]')->item( 2);

// Echo Variable's
if(isset($price30in)) { echo $price30in->textContent;} if(isset($price30out)) { echo ", " . $price30out->textContent; }

// The wrong CODE i tried:
// $uphalfh = if(isset($price30in)) { echo $price30in->textContent;}
// if(isset($price30out)) { echo ", " . $price30out->textContent; }


// Create post object
  $my_post = array();
  $my_post['post_title'] = 'MyTitle';
  $my_post['post_content'] = 'MyDesciprion';
  $my_post['post_status'] = 'draft';
  $my_post['post_author'] = 1;

// Insert the post into the database
$post_id =  wp_insert_post( $my_post );
update_post_meta($post_id,'30_min',$uphalfh);
```

Comment: `$var=if()` is just wrong syntax.

Comment: If you have `$price29in`, `$price28in`, etc... you should read up on [variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) or arrays.

Comment: you got learn php very neatly. Find a documentation about php [here](http://php.net/manual/en/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$uphalfh = isset($price30in);

if(isset($price30in)) { 
    echo $price30in->textContent;
}
if(isset($price30out)) {
   echo ", " . $price30out->textContent; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

remove the assignment.

```
if(isset($price30in)) { echo $price30in->textContent;}
if(isset($price30out)) { echo ", " . $price30out->textContent; }
```

Comment: This code works well: `if(isset($price30in)) { echo "<br />" . $price30in->textContent;} if(isset($price30out)) { echo ", " . $price30out->textContent; }` How can I add the result of this code to $var ?

Comment: @Cyborg you're going about it the wrong way. Check out my answer.

Comment: @Cyborg `$varPrice30in = (isset($price30in))?$price30in->textContent:'';
$varPrice30out = (isset($price30out))?", " . $price30out->textContent:'';`

Answer (score 1):

```
// $uphalfh = you have to complete the variable initialising here and then continue with the conditional statement or remove the variable initialising and continue with the conditional statement because $var = if(conditon){ }else{ }; is wrong syntax in php
if(isset($price30in)) { 
   echo $price30in->textContent;
}
if(isset($price30out)) {
   echo ", " . $price30out->textContent; 
}
```

Comment: Can you explain reason for downvotting @downvotter.

Answer (score 0):

```
 echo $uphalf = (isset($price30in)) ? $price30in->textContent : "";
```

Answer (score 0):

The `if` clause does not return a value, which means you can't use it in the context of assigning a value to variable because there is no value to be had.

```
$uphalfh = if(isset($price30in)) {
    echo $price30in->textContent;
} if(isset($price30out)) {
    echo ", " . $price30out->textContent;
}
```

The above code will not work as you expected it, the bellow code should work as expected -- the value of `$uphalf` will be set to either `$price30in->textContent` or  `$price30out->textContent`.

```
if(isset($price30in)) {
    $uphalfh = $price30in->textContent;
} if(isset($price30out)) {
    $uphalfh = ", " . $price30out->textContent;
}
```

Only if you also want this result to be outputted to the browser (directly visible to a visitor) you could use `echo`.

```
if(isset($price30in)) {
    $uphalfh = $price30in->textContent;
}
if(isset($price30out)) {
    $uphalfh = ", " . $price30out->textContent;
}
echo $uphalfh;
```

Comment: Please take a look at my updated question. Any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: My example should work correctly, `$uphalfh` should be assigned a value based on which of the `if` conditions is satisfied.

Comment: @Cyborg did you by any chance intend to have the value of both nodes? Not just one of them?

Answer (score 0):

**A simple edit did the trick! That solved my problem :-)**

I replaced:

```
$uphalfh = if(isset($price30in)) { echo $price30in->textContent;}
if(isset($price30out)) { echo ", " . $price30out->textContent; }
```

With this:

```
$uphalfh = $price30in->textContent. ', ' . $price30out->textContent;
```